# Change display in separate field using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

When I click a checkbox it updates a display field, I would like to capture what is in the display field and also show it in a different display field. In a perfect world the second field (which is a total field) would add or subtract what was shown in the first field from it's contents.

Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="amputeeGolfer" type="checkbox" id="amputeeGolfer" value="amputee" onchange="toggleAmputee(this,50.00)"/>
        <label for="amputeeGolfer">Amputee Golfer</label></td>
    <td align="left"><label for="amputeeFee">$50.00</label></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input name="amputeeFee" type="number" id="amputeeFee" class="tblRight" size="10" value="0.00" readonly="readonly"/></td>
 </tr>
```

jquery

```
<script>
    function toggleAmputee(element,price){
    if(element.checked){
        document.getElementById("amputeeFee").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("amputeeFee").value) + price;
        $('#amputeeFee').change(function() {
            $('#totalFees').val($(this).val());
        });
    }else{
        document.getElementById("amputeeFee").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("amputeeFee").value) - price;
    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail. what you actuality want

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to sum all checkbox values? Then try this.

```
<div id="c_b">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="10" onchange="calc()"> bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="20" onchange="calc()"> car<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="50" onchange="calc()"> boat<br>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="t" readonly />
</div>

function calc() {
    var allVals = 0;
     $('#c_b :checked').each(function() {
       allVals += parseInt($(this).val());
     });
     $('#t').val(allVals);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery script as follow
https://jsfiddle.net/8Ly1b4d3/

```
//html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <tr>
      <td><input name="amputeeGolfer" type="checkbox" id="amputeeGolfer" value="amputee"/>
      <label for="amputeeGolfer">Amputee Golfer</label></td>
      <td align="left"><label for="amputeeFee" id="amputeeFee">$50.00</label></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input name="amputeeFee" type="number" id="newAmputeeFee" class="tblRight" size="10" value="0.00" readonly="readonly"/></td>
   </tr>

//jquery
   $('#amputeeGolfer').change(function(){
     var price = 50.00;
     var value = $('#amputeeFee').text();
     value = value.replace('$','');
     if($('#amputeeGolfer'). prop("checked") == true){
       var new_value = parseInt(value) + parseInt(price);
     } else { 
       new_value = parseInt(value) - parseInt(price);
     }
     $('#newAmputeeFee').val(new_value);
   });
```